# Changing colorbar of pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have plotted a graph using the dataframe `plot` method:

```
ax = df1.plot(x='Lat', y='Lon', kind='scatter', c='Thickness')
```

The result is a scatter plot where the dots are scaled to the parameter set in `c='Thickness'`. The colorbar next to the graph automatically receives the label `Thickness`. I would like to change it.

I know about the colorbar method `set_label`, but I do not know how to access the colorbar object from the `ax` returned by pandas' `plot` function.

How can I access the colorbar object in the plot in order to change its label?

---

To clarify, I have added the picture of the graph. I am interested in changing the label of the colorbar. [image]

Comment: Is the `Thickness` parameter categorical?

Comment: No, the data consists of numbers. All doubles.

Comment: So you want to change 'Thickness' to something else, right?

Comment: Try using `set_label` as in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html).

Comment: Indeed, I want to change "Thickness" to "Thickness (cm)" . I could change the name of the column in the dataframe...but I want to now how to access the colorbar object. 
I am aware there is a `set_label` function, however, I don't know how to access to colorbar object. dataframe.plt() doesn't return a colorbar object...this is where my issue lies. I finding the way to access the colorbar object after having created a plot using pandas.datarame.plt()

Comment: I have edited your question to add the `matplotlib` tag. This will bump it and should show it to more competent people.

Comment: I think I've found [the answer you're looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33242080/5276797).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Colorbar instance of scatter plot in pandas/matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240427/getting-colorbar-instance-of-scatter-plot-in-pandas-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too complicated to use `pandas` for setting `colorbar`'s label. You can use `matplotlib.pyplot` directly, this is an example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
ymin = y.min()
ymax = y.max()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, figsize=(7, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, left=0.07, right=0.93)
ax = axs[0]
hb = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=50, cmap='inferno')
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.set_title("Hexagon binning")
cb = fig.colorbar(hb, ax=ax)
cb.set_label('counts')

ax = axs[1]
hb = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=50, bins='log', cmap='inferno')
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.set_title("With a log color scale")
cb = fig.colorbar(hb, ax=ax)
cb.set_label('log10(N)')

plt.show()
```

ref: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin

Comment: It's not too complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240427/getting-colorbar-instance-of-scatter-plot-in-pandas-matplotlib/33242080#33242080