# Change colorbar in Geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

**The Problem**

How can I access the colorbar instance created when plotting a GeoDataFrame? In this example, I've plotted troop movements and sizes during the French invasion of Russia, with army sizes less than 10000 plotted in red. How do I get the colorbar to show that red means under 10000?

MCVE:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import geopandas as gpd

# ingest troop movement data
PATH = ("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/"
        "Minard.troops.csv")
troops = pd.read_csv(PATH)
troops['geometry'] = troops.apply(lambda row: Point(row.long, row.lat), axis=1)
troops = gpd.GeoDataFrame(troops)

# get army group paths
grouped = troops.groupby('group')
groups = [[LineString(group[['long', 'lat']].values), name]
          for name, group in grouped]
groups = pd.DataFrame(groups, columns=['geometry', 'army group'])
groups = gpd.GeoDataFrame(groups)
groups.plot(color=['red', 'green', 'blue'], lw=0.5)

# plot troop sizes
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('cool')
cmap.set_under('red')
troops.plot(column='survivors', ax=plt.gca(),
            cmap=cmap, vmin=10000, legend=True, markersize=50)
```

Output:

[image]

Here, `legend=True` in the last line adds the colorbar.

**Attempts at a solution**

I know that if I made the colorbar myself, I could just pass the argument `extend='min'` to add a red triangle to the bottom of the colorbar.

And I know I can get the colorbar axes through (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33242080/4691830)):

```
cax = plt.gcf().axes[1]
```

but I don't know how that helps me edit the colorbar. I can't even add a label with `cax.set_label('troop size')`. (i.e. I can't see that label anywhere although `cax.get_label()` does return 'troop size')

These axes appear to consist of two polygons:

```
In[315]: cax.artists
Out[315]: 
[<matplotlib.patches.Polygon at 0x1e0e73c8>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Polygon at 0x190c8f28>]
```

No idea what to make of that. And even if I could find the actual colorbar instance, I wouldn't know how to extend it as the [docs for the `Colorbar` class](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.Colorbar) don't mention anything like that.

**Alternatives**

1. Is there a way to pass the `extend` keyword through the `GeoDataFrame.plot` function?
2. Can I somehow access the colorbar instance by either saving it when plotting or finding it in the figure?
3. How would I go about constructing the colorbar directly with Matplotlib? And how do I avoid that it deviates from the plot if I change parameters?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't an answer to your question, well it isn't directly anyways.  For most of my graphing I've had great success with using pygal http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/line.html

Comment: Sidenote: for the label, you want `ylabel` instead of `label`: `cax.set_ylabel('troop size')` (or for above: `set_title`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue (and PR) about making it possible to pass keywords to the colorbar construction: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/697.
But for now, the best work-around is to create the colorbar yourself I think:

Create the same figure but with `legend=False`:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('cool')
cmap.set_under('red')
ax = troops.plot(column='survivors', cmap=cmap, vmin=10000, legend=False, markersize=50)
```

Now, we get the collection created for the points (from a scatter plot) as the first element of the `ax.collections`, so we can instruct matplotlib to create a colorbar based on this mapping (and now we can pass additional keywords):

```
scatter = ax.collections[0]
plt.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, extend='min')
```

this gives me

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's ax.collections[1] with the full code I posted (including the army group paths). The safest general solution is probably to write `scatter = ax.collections[-1]` right after the plot command.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed with multiple plots you need to be careful to get the correct one!