# X-axis label doesn't show on Pandas DataFrame plot with colorbar

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I want to make a pandas.DataFrame.plot with colorbar. For reproducibility, here I use the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240427/getting-colorbar-instance-of-scatter-plot-in-pandas-matplotlib) on stack overflow.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it

# [ (0,0), (0,1), ..., (9,9) ]
xy_positions = list( it.product( range(10), range(10) ) )

df = pd.DataFrame( xy_positions, columns=['x','y'] )

# draw 100 floats
df['score'] = np.random.random( 100 )

ax = df.plot( kind='scatter',
              x='x',
              y='y',
              c='score',
              s=500,
              xlabel='x')
ax.set_xlim( [-0.5,9.5] )
ax.set_ylim( [-0.5,9.5] )
plt.tight_layout()
```

However, in my environment the figure doesn't show x-axis somehow. So I try to add `ax.set_xlabel("x label")` in the code, but the output doesn't change.

[image: Figure]

Here are the package versions of my Python environment.

- Python 3.8.12
- pandas 1.4.0
- matplotlib 3.5.1

Is there any suggestion of this issue? Thanks!

Additional information: I use macOS Big Sur version 11.6 on MacBook Pro M1.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Pandas 1.4.1, Python 3.9.7, Matplotlib 3.4.3

Comment: I also have the issue (no x): `pandas 1.4.1, matplotlib 3.3.2`

Comment: No problems matplotlib 3.5.1 Python 3.8 Windows 10 PyQt5 backend.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for your suggestion, but I got an error... `'PathCollection' object has no property 'x_compat'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('Greys')

sc = ax.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], s=500, c=df['score'],
                vmin=df['score'].min(), vmax=df['score'].max(), cmap=cm)
cb = fig.colorbar(sc)
t = cb.set_label('score', rotation=-90)

ax.set_xlim( [-0.5,9.5] )
ax.set_ylim( [-0.5,9.5] )
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh it is another solution, thanks. It worked for me!  But I still wonder why the issue happens.